# Must Make a Major Modification of Medieval Metallurgy

Tags: science-based, medieval, technological-development, metals

The scene:  Earth, but with a single major modification, the addition of a HUGE quantity of a single element to the Earth's **crust** (bringing it up to the same abundance as Iron **in the crust**).

The element:  The added element must have a density equal to, or greater than, Palladium.  It must be stable under standard conditions.  It must occur naturally in the real Earth's crust already, though it need not be in a native state, ores are ok.  It must not be hazardous to humans (eg. no Mercury or Plutonium).  It must be something that would have a significant influence on pre-1500 (the year 1500 or earlier) metalworking technological advancement, though it need not be a metal itself (eg. Carbon is not a metal but has a huge significance in metals tech).

The actual question:  Which element (meeting the above criteria), if it had been so much more abundant and available in the crust than it actually is, would have caused the most dramatically different development in metalworking than what actually happened in history?

**EDIT** Apparently the purpose of the question is regarded by potential answerers as more important than I originally anticipated.  So to explain it briefly: I'm building a world that is smaller but more dense than Earth, to yield earth-like gravity.  I'm doing this by adding more dense material(s) to it.  This question was intended to help me understand some of the likely implications of this element being available in greater quantities than on earth to technological advancement of civilizations that are placed on this world for the story, which takes place in a roughly medieval tech level.  Emphasis added to "in the crust" to indicate that changes to the overall density to Earth, and gravity, etc., are outside the scope of the question.  **Other than the element is more available for metalworking/metallurgy/etc., other effects on the Earth can be disregarded.**

Comment: "The most dramatically different development" is probably too opinion-based. There aren't that many elements meeting your criteria, so you might try narrowing it down to one or two specific metals and editing your question to focus on them. (As far as I can tell, taking your density requirement and cutting out radioactive and synthetic elements leaves gold, tungsten, various platinum-group metals, and a few scattered transition metals.)

Comment: Just as a warning, increasing the abundance of any material denser than palladium to the quantities of Iron is going to significantly increase the mass of the planet. Most of the iron on earth is at the core, but a denser material is going to have an even lower surface to core ratio. So I'd avoid the "same availability as Iron" criteria before you work yourself into a "there are no trees because too much gravity" scenario.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Why palladium - is this purely arbitrary or are you actually expecting some particular traits? Is there an actual purpose or is this purely arbitrary conditions? Why haven't you just googled the list of elements by density and looked past palladium?

Comment: @Stephan Yup, I'm hoping for that increased density/gravity, actually ...

Comment: @pluckedkiwi I picked dense materials intentionally, to increase the density of the planet, but left that out of the actual question, as the consequences of that density and the workarounds I will put in place are beyond the scope of the question itself.

Comment: @Cadence I understand that risk, but I'm hoping that between the specific application to metallurgy, the limitation on available elements, along with science-based, is enough to limit opinions for the most part.

Comment: Just a rough back of the envelope calculation: Iron is 35% of the earths mass. Silver is 1.8 times the mass of Iron. For it to exist in equivalent quantities, it would add roughly 60% of earths current mass to itself. You're looking at a gravity at sea level roughly 25% more than current. I think at the very least, you're talking lower melting points for everything, and smaller structures because self-weight would be a bigger factor in construction.

Comment: @Dalila Your question should then specify that your purpose is to increase the density of the planet as well as influence the development of metallurgy. Availability in the crust is largely irrelevant to the density of the planet anyway - you're not significantly changing the planet as a whole by a slight alteration in the outermost skin of the planet. The composition of the core and mantle is more pertinent, which would not necessarily be reflected in the crust.

Comment: @Stephan I've got solutions planned for all of that, and it's all really beside the point of the question.  If you really want to know, I'm trying to make a non-earth planet more dense, but smaller, yielding earthlike gravity.  I'm adding dense material to increase the density, and this question is meant to help me address how those added materials will affect the civilizations that I later place on the planet for the story.  But, for the intents and purposes of this question, it can be "effectively" Earth, just with mines of something that we don't have mines for now.

Comment: @pluckedkiwi  The purpose is not to increase the density, but rather the other way around.  I've already increased the density (and decreased overall size to make it earthlike gravity), and I'm trying to find out what the results of that increase will be on the histories of the civilizations that live there, assuming everything else stays "earthlike" other than this dense stuff is now more available.

Comment: The crust represents less than 1% of the Earth's total mass. Iron represents 5.6% of the crust by mass, so (being generous) crustal iron is 0.056% of the planet's overall mass. If you doubled the amount of iron, the gravity at Earth's surface would increase by roughly 0.006 g. If you tripled? 0.011 g. In other words, you'd have to add a ridiculously obscene amount of the element to the crust to significantly impact the planet's gravity.

Comment: @KeithMorrison  I understand.  But the point is to have it be Earthlike, other than additional element availability in the crust.  I'll deal with the gravity, density, and whatnot, separately from this question.  This question is about the metalworking changes, nothing else.

Comment: There are very few minerals denser than palladium, and the only one which is even moderately useful is gold.

Comment: Mightn't it just be easier to change the gravitational constant of the universe?  You know, so that you get the gravity you want with whatever size planted you've decided on? Also, you won't have to worry about medieval metallurgy. As a metal, palladium just isn't that interesting or useful.  In such a world as you propose, it might be useful for cheap tarnish resistant plate and flatware... Tin and lead are denser and might be more useful commercially.

Comment: I edited your tags to include [metals] which seemed pretty important.  I removed the [alternate-earth] and [alternate-history] tags because you're not writing about Earth, you're writing about an Earth-like planet that has different metals available for use by intelligent beings.  Feel free to change this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more I think about this, I think any significant increase in planetary density would probably negatively impact the use of metals in general.

We've known about metals for a very very long time, but only really put them to use beyond decoration and cutting implements very recently in human history. Iron wasn't valued for weapons or armor until it's alloy with carbon was discovered, as it was too heavy otherwise. Steel wasn't even used for construction until around the construction of the Eiffel Tower in 1889. Gold was thought useless for anything but ornamentation and currency until its electrical properties were recognized, again, very recently.

I think if the planet were significantly more dense, the usefulness of metals would take an even longer time to be recognized, as the gravity would reduce the useful loads of these materials. Stonework and concrete would likely remain the construction material of choice.

It's also important to note that increasing the mass of the planet is going to affect the availability of all elements in the crust. Elements tend to sort themselves into layers over time due to their own specific gravity.

Edit:

Since the comments clarify that the planet would be smaller, but denser to net out at the same surface gravity, that changes things.

Silver, Tin, Platinum, Gold and Lead are the only metals I know of in that criteria that aren't inherently hazardous and have any major usefulness to a Medieval society.

Platinum is a hard metal to use, so likely wouldn't change anything significantly. Even platinum coins are difficult to strike.

Silver being so plentiful might make everyone blue blooded or blue skinned(literally).

Gold would likely increase its use as decoration, and it'd probably still be the primary commodity of trade. Gold shingles on roofs might be part of their construction methods.

Lead would leak so much radiation at those quantities that people would probably be dead.

Comment: *"Iron wasn't valued for weapons or armor until it's alloy with carbon was discovered:"* what alloy with carbon -- steel or cast iron? And it's anyway definitely not true; the iron swords and tools of the Iron Age (including, for example, Roman swords) were made of soft iron. *"Lead would leak so much radiation":* could you please elaborate? The five naturally occurring unstable isotopes of lead have negligible abundance.

Comment: [According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron_Age) `the term "Iron Age" implies that the production of carbon steel has been perfected to the point where mass production of tools and weapons superior to their bronze equivalents become possible`.  And as far as lead, I'm sure it's negligible until you have roughly half the mass of your planet being composed of decayed radioactive material a.k.a. lead. But then again, I'm not a chemist.

Comment: In the matter of steel, Wikipedia is painfully wrong. I have edited the article in question and inserted some requests for citations, in the hope that future readers will realise that the article author's insistence of steel has no basis. In the matter of lead, "negligible" means trace amounts; for all practical purpose lead is not radioactive -- lead is much less radioactive than human flesh, for example.

Comment: I wasn't aware the half-life was so short with lead. Still would be a lead poisoning risk for ground water, unless the population evolved there natively and their bodies can deal.

Comment: It may be worth pointing out that there are trace amounts of radioactive material in, essentially, *anything* that isn't sufficiently purified. This is actually [a major problem for computers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_error#Alpha_particles_from_package_decay).

Answer (score 6):

## Gold

It is one of the most malleable and least reactive elements. If it were more available from ancient times people would be making more things with it... If it were as abundant as iron, for example, I imagine people would not covet it so much. Rather than writing with ink on paper, people would be writing important documents and books by carving on thin golden sheets which could last for millenia.

A lot of the knowledge from ancient times that was lost during the dark ages might never be lost in such a scenario. Technological progress before the modern age would be faster and more resilient to disasters and human shenaningans due to this more durable means of knowledge preservation and spreading.

Comment: Gold is no more useful than lead in this respect. Why do you think gold would be used like this?

Comment: Gold is more malleable than lead. You can easily fold a small golden die into a 2 square meters sheet. You can't do that with lead.

Comment: This could be feasible using some sort of chisel-like tool, scribing with a tactile symbol system (i.e. Braille). Sense the contrast between symbols and the surface would be low, using eyes to actually read the content would be difficult. Tactile systems would also allow ease of use in the dark.

Comment: Hard to believe. The main drivers for metal use are tools, weapons and construction, and the gold is too heavy and too malleable for all of these. Also, inscriptions on clay tablets can survive some disasters even better than gold, but they were abandoned in favor of vellum, paper, etc. for convenience.

Comment: @Renan, you can also tear that sheet easier than you could paper.

Comment: *"A lot of the knowledge from ancient times that was lost during the dark ages:"* it is extremely highly debatable whether any important knowledge was lost during the early Middle Ages (which is what I suppose you mean by "dark ages"). Could you give an example of an important piece of knowledge which the ancient had, but was lost and had to be rediscovered in the Renaissance or later?

Comment: @Renan Lead is still highly malleable and easily hammered/rolled into sheets with very little additional effort compared to gold. If people wanted sheets of metal to write on, they could have used lead, so making gold as available as iron would not have inspired the use of gold as writing medium. People had no interest in metal sheets like that. Some plaques were made in metal but that tended to be in bronze. Nobody had an interest in soft metal sheets but were *only* put off by the high price for gold.

Comment: @AlexP I'm not sure asking for an example of something that was lost is possible to answer. It was lost, so how would anyone know they knew it? :p

Comment: @Stephan: Then how does one know that it was lost?

Comment: @AlexP because we know tangentially, like the records about the loss of the library of alexandria. We know it was a massive collection, but not the specific knowledge it contained.

Comment: @Stephan: So if future generations learn that once upon a time there was a massive collection of short text messages known and the Tweeter, which was lost in the great data storage upheaval of the 25th century, they can safely infer that a lot of important knowledge was lost forever?

Comment: I don't see anyone qualifying the importance of the knowledge, only that it was lost, and gold, being non-volatile and stable, would have been a better preservation medium for ancient knowledge. Doesn't matter how obscure or trivial the knowledge.

Comment: @AlexP how about Eratosthenes's demonstration of how the Earth is not flat?

Comment: @Renan: Erathosthenes did not demonstrate that the Earth is not flat -- that was known since the deepest antiquity, at least by sailors and astronomers. What Eratosthenes did was determine the size of the Earth; and his calculation was never lost, and indeed it was used in Ptolemy's *Geography*, which formed the basis of geographical knowledge up to the Age of Discoveries.

Comment: Gold is the best answer.  If it were more common it would be hugely useful especially to preindustrial people.   It occurs native in metallic form so you do not need any tech - you can work it with a rock.  Unlike lead and copper it will not oxidize even in seawater.  You could sheathe your ships in gold and they would be immune to shipworms.  A gold leaf roof is good forever.  Using stone age tech you could make a frying pan out of gold which will stay shiny and not poison you.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer is - no.

Elemental densities are well-known, and listed [here](https://www.angstromsciences.com/density-elements-chart). There are 19 known elements denser than palladium, and 8 of those are radioactive. Of the remaining 11, the only three "common" ones are mercury, gold, and platinum, none of which have much metallurgical magic unknown in 1500. Elements like tungsten and iridium are pretty much unworkable with 1500's technology, and the remainder simply don't have a lot going for them in revolutionary terms.